# When calling New on an object, can the object being created refer back to its caller?

Tags: vb.net

I hope the question makes sense, anyways.  I'm looking to know if in VB.NET, when we call an object's constructor, is there some kind of a reference that points back to the caller?

I'm interested because of a corner case where I want the object being created to first be able to validate the existence of some data in the caller before it allows itself to be created.  If this validation fails, I plan on throwing an exception.  This corner case will never happen at runtime unless the object being created is used improperly by a programmer.  The object being created is **not** inheriting the object I want it to validate, so I can't do anything with the `MyBase` qualifier.

It's bit of a "future-proofing" issue that I have a (bad) habit of doing.  Not critical -- I can always leave stern comments behind as a last resort.  Wanted to know if this was possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a built-in reference to the caller, but the caller could pass a reference to itself as a parameter to the constructor.

Comment: I didn't think so, but wanted to be sure.  I think I've found a solution to my problem.  I'll post more later after the Ravens/Falcons game.

Comment: So what I did was to encode a "Max" value (I'm basically building static classes to mimic .NET Enums), and used that to check an array as the first item in the constructor.  If the array is not null, and already equals the "max" value, then I can throw the exception.  The idea is the enums are fixed, and will not change often, so making them a compile-time thing is sensible.  When they do need to be updated, it's the responsibility of the programmer (me right now) to add new items and increment the "max" value.  This way, enums that are added outside of the class will always fail.

Answer (score 1):

There's no way for an object to refer back to its caller.  It is possible to specify that a 'parent object' must be passed in as a parameter (as suggested by ChrisF), but there's no guarantee that the passed-in object will have any relation to the actual caller.  If your goal is to "attach" yourself to an object, however, this method will ensure that you have a valid object to attach to.

A useful trick which is available in VB.Net, but not C#, is to have a base type which has a field of some particular type, and sets that field to a value passed in its constructor.  In VB.net, derived-type field initializations are performed between the call to the base-level constructor and the next statement in the constructor.  Thus, one can do something like:

```
Class ParamBase(Of T)
  Protected BaseParam As T
  Sub New(TheParam As T)
    BaseParam = Param
  End Sub
End Class

Class MyThing
  Inherits ParamBase(Of MyThingParent)

  ' Sample initialization
  Dim MyTitle = BaseParam.Title ' Assuming MyThingParent has a title property
  ' Other initializations can be done similarly

  Sub New(MyParent As MyThingParent)
    MyBase.New(MyParent)
    ' Do remainder of constructor
  End Sub
End Class
```

Handy little trick.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a constructor that takes the creating object as parameter and then make the default constructor private so it can't be called:

```
Public Class Example

Private Sub New() 
End Sub 

Public Sub New(ByVal parent as object) 
'initialisation code 
End Sub 

End Class
```

(apologies if the syntax isn't 100% correct)